# How do I find resource id from items within my listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-resources

G'day again!

Trying to work out a good approach to finding a resource id for an item that lives within a listview.

So basically I pull data from a website and add them into my android app's listview. Currently I have a placeholder image, and two text fields. The intention being that after the initial text data has been pulled from the website (which includes a URL for each individual image), I would then go through the list again launching async tasks to download the image and then make it display in the listview.

But how do I go about finding the resource ID for each of the ImageViews within my listview?

In my adventures of reading tutorials and thinking I've got my head around it, but actually have not, I came across the concept of creating my own Adapter class based off the BaseAdapter. I think I get how its structured, but I don't quite get how its useful for my case (if its even useful at all?)

Anyone got an idea on how to approach this?

```
...

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  allUserList;
ListView listview_usersId;

...

allUserList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
listview_usersId = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_users);

...

private void UpdateUserListWithContent() {

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            UserlistActivity.this,
            allUserList,
            R.layout.list_userliststyle,
            new String[]{TAG_ID, TAG_USERNAME},
            new int[]{R.id.list_userliststyle_id, R.id.list_userliststyle_username});
    // updating listview
    listview_usersId.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I was sort of hoping for something along the lines of...

```
theIdIWant = myListView[position].magicalFunctionThatKnowsWhatResourceIWant(imageView).resourceId()
```

If that even makes sense?

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: add your SimpleAdapter class code

Comment: Picaso is good for getting the images, didn't see anything about it being useful for getting resource IDs from listviews.... The SimpleAdapter is part of the standard "android.widget". BUT Looking at the code there appears to be a "getView" function that might be what I'm after so I'll do a bit of reading up on that :)

Answer (score 1):

As from your question, you would like to load an image from an url for each row items. In my opinion, you'd be better off working with a custom adapter based off the BaseAdapter. You actually do not need to reference each ImageView separately via its resource id. A list view actually recycles rows so that it does not have to create view's for each items in the list in order to save precious memory. Also, for each view item, the resource id remains the same (R.id.exampleimageview).

Here is a short implementation of an adapter that would load items off a JSON Array and uses Picasso library (which is a great library intended to load images off the internet) to load image to the image view for that row:

```
public class JSONListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
     private Context mContext;
     private JSONArray data;
     public JSONListAdapter(Context mContext,JSONArray data){
         this.mContext=mContext;
         this.data=data;
     }
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length();
      //return number of rows in your list
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dataList[position];
       //return items for each position
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        }

        String row=data.get(position);

            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.example_textview)).setText(row.getString("title"));
//Now to load image which is stored in imgurl to your view.
String imageURL=row.getString("imgurl");

  //Use Picasso library to load image to this image view

   ImageView myImageView=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exampleimageview);

   Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageURL).into(myImageView);

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

I hope I was clear with this.For this however, you would need to add picasso as a library to your project. Assuming you are using Android Studio,  just add compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0' - to your dependencies.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I ended up modifying things to do my own Adapter which downloads stuff on the fly. Seems to work pretty well so far cheers for that. It helped me get my head around it all.

Comment: Im glad it did. But there is a substitute to a ListView / GridView now called a "RecyclerView". I suggest you look into it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the images from server and set it on the ImageView i would suggest to use Picasso or Volley for that, but for your second that is completely valid to get the id of the view when you are going to edit some item in the row for that let say you want to edit the image of the 3rd item in the list and for that:

1. You just have to ask the list to get the view at the 3rd position using the getview method.
2. Find the imageview using the findviewById.
3. Set any image either local or a url to this image.

To get view using position use the following method:

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

If I got anything wrong please mention.

Comment: I ended up changing my code a little to download the pictures through a custom adapter. But I have a feeling I'm going to need to use the example above at some point int he future, so I'll have a better idea then if it works and such :)

Answer (score 0):

> The intention being that after the initial text data has been pulled
>   from the website (which includes a URL for each individual image), I
>   would then go through the list again launching async tasks to download
>   the image and then make it display in the listview.

This is not a good idea.

You must implement `getView` in your `SimpleAdapter`, and launch the AsyncTask to download the image there. That way tasks will be launched only when needed: when the item becomes visible after scrolling, basically.

Also, I recomend you to have a look to [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) instead of implementing your own AsyncTask. It has a cache as well, so increases performance, and only requires on line of code.

Comment: Yeah picasso library seems to be the way to go when it comes to downloading the image. But I imagine there may be times in the future I still need to edit one of the elements in the list by a resource id or something, eg, update something somehow. I read up on the **getView** just then and I understand it a little more, so I might try something with it. But yeah still would like to know how to get resource IDs for things in the list.

Comment: You must update the views in the `getView` method. If you want to update data, i.e. updating an image url, text, ... update the model objects (you should store objects in an array and pass it to the adapter constructor, instead of passing anonymous arrays as you are doing) and invoke `yourAdapter.notifiyDataSetChanged()`. It will tell the adapter to update the views, therefore will invoke the `getView` for needed items and views will be updated. I encourage you to check a simple custom adapter example to get a better idea of how to do it.